# How to make excessive daydreaming affect daily activities less?

Tags: pre-schooler, social-development

My 5-year old child daydreams a lot. I know daydreaming is essentially a positive thing. However, she misses instructions in class, and is always last because of that - she has to look at the other kids to figure out what the instructions were. Often she's unable to finish her assignments in time.

Also, something like putting on her clothes or going to the bathroom can easily take 20 to 30 minutes if I let her daydream.

She sleeps 12 hours a day, which seems enough. What can I do to make her daily activities less affected by daydreaming?

Comment: Maybe more interaction would help. Since daydreaming is typically a solo act, active engagement might help her focus. My 5 year old certainly wastes a lot of time with normal activities but it's more distractions than daydreaming. when I am doing things with her it moves a lot faster without me having to do it for her. I know it's probably not possible to actually do that all the time, but just whenever you can.

Comment: One of the symptoms of ADHD, especially in girls, is a tendency to excessively daydream and end up not paying attention.  It might be something to bring up to her doctor.

Answer (score 1):

As this is happening primarily at school, it will mostly be up to the teacher to try to engage the child more. There's not a great deal you can do about it yourself. You could give a gentle reminder "now remember to listen carefully to your teacher", each morning when you drop her off at school. Don't push this too much though, just make it the last thing you say to her each morning.
Otherwise you could try to find ways to reward good performance at school, like some kind of treat for finishing her work.